# How to sort out only terms that relates to certain variable in the results of TrigReduce?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I have a large function $F(\theta,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...)$ which involves only trigonometric polynomial of these angles. I want to calculate $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} Fd\theta$, but the function is too large so it takes a long time. But if I use TrigReduce on $F$, it is obvious that the terms independent of $\theta$ (in the result of TrigReduce) are exactlly the results I desire since the integration of other terms naturally vanish. How can I sort out these terms directly from the result to avoid the integration that takes a long time?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include a sample expression so that respondents can work with it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try a `MemberQ` function?

Comment: `Collect` also might work, depending on the details of the expression..